# Mass required for a certain fusion process

Tags: star, nucleosynthesis

Suppose we have a density model

$$ρ = ρ_c (1-r/R)$$

where $ρ$ is density, ${}_c$ means central, and $R$ is the stellar radius.

Let's call the temperature for that fusion process to begin, $T_f$.

I want to know the minimal stellar mass for a certain fusion to begin.
I made some assumptions, for example the values of X, Y, and μ. So if the gas is non degenerative and non relativistic, we have

$$P = \dfrac{ρκΤ}{μm_h}$$

But im not sure what to do with the pressure. I have $T,μ$, can obtain $ρ(M,R)$. Maybe I can use virial?

Comment: What fusion process are you considering? Hydrogen? Helium? Or heavier?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.